# Change automatically generated Text in sources with natbib

Tags: natbib, source

In my source directory of the thesis I am currently working on, I have got a masters's thesis as one source. As type for this source I chose Master thesis and now Latex always writes "master's thesis" inside my german source directory. Is there a way to change this to "Masterarbeit"?

Comment: Please, add the `.bib` entry to your question; however, including in it the field `type={Masterarbeit},` should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `mastersthesis` entry accepts a `type` field:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@mastersthesis{x,
 author={Me Myself},
 title={My thesis},
 type={Masterarbeit},
 school={That School},
 year={2020},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{x}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]